# Formatar numero de telefone como (00) 00000-0000

Tags: php

Tenho um problema com a formatação dos numeros de telefone em meu site escrito em PHP.

Neste formulário, o usuário digita seu numero de telefone:

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="phoneMobile">
        <?php _e('Whatsapp "Recomendado"',); ?> <sup>*</sup>
      </label>
      <div class="controls">
        <?php UserForm::mobile_text(osc_user()); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
```

depois de salvo todo processo,o telefone aparece no perfil do usuário:

```
<li>
<h3>Whatsapp</h3>
<h1 class="name"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i><?php printf('%s', osc_user_phone_mobile()); ?></h1>
</li>
```

Eu estou procurando uma maneira de o numero aparecer formatado no seguinte padrão (xx) xxxxx-xxxx sem usar plugins ou JS. O formulário é Bootstrap.

Comment: Precisa ser PHP? Certeza que existe uma máscara em JS que já trata disso com perfeição. De toda sorte, muita gente precisa formatar números de telefone. Acho que se procurar por "máscara telefone" aqui mesmo no site encontrará uma pergunta duplicata desta sua, já devidamente respondida

Comment: Não precisa ser php, ja pesquisei sim... inclusive tenho varios exemplos de mascaras aqui. Minha duvida é como, e onde vou colocar esses códigos? Todas as formas que tentei não deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Tem uma solução bem simples utilizando o plugin jquery.mask

Primeiro, você pode encontrar o jquery.mask nesse link: https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Depois, no seu arquivo JS, basta colocar essa função:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#telefone").mask("(00) 00000-0000")
})
```

Com esse pequeno trecho de código todos os seus campos com id "telefone" já estarão com a máscara definida.

Veja esse exemplo funcionando aqui: http://natuqualy.com.br/seja-representante

Comment: Esta é a grande questão... Estou usando um CMS, com pastas e arquivos a perder de vista, um ponto esquecido e o "error" come souto... Onde devo colocar este plugin? ( em um tipo de pasta especifica? na pasta raiz?) ... e outra: "o que seria meu arquivo "JS" ? e onde neste arquivo JS eu devo colocar seu código? minha pasta js tem mais de 10 arquivos JS...